# Read compressed JSON file from s3 in chunks and write each chunk to parquet

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, parquet

I'm trying to get a 20GB JSON gzipped file from s3 in chunks, decompress each chunk, convert the chunk to parquet, and then save it to another bucket.

I have the following code that works well with smaller files, however, when I try to perform this with the 20GB files I get the following traceback below. I'm not entirely sure how to resolve this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    data = gzip.decompress(chunk) "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 548, in decompress
    return f.read()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 292, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 498, in read
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/samlambert/Desktop/Repos/hdns/src/collection/data_converter.py", line 33, in <module>
    data = gzip.decompress(chunk)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 548, in decompress
    return f.read()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 292, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 498, in read
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

```
with S3() as s3:
    # get s3 object (20GB gzipped JSON file)
    obj = s3.s3_client.get_object(Bucket=input_bucket, Key=object_key)

    # Separate the file into chunks
    for chunk in obj['Body'].iter_chunks():
        
        decompress and decode
        data = gzip.decompress(chunk)
        text = data.decode('utf-8')

        # At this point chunk is one string with multiple lines of JSON
        # We convert each line into it's own JSON, then append json_data
        data_in_list = text.splitlines()
        json_data = []
        for data in data_in_list:
            string_to_json = json.loads(data)
            json_data.append(string_to_json)

        # Convert list of JSON objs into one dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
        
        convert df to parquet and save to s3
        parquet_filename = 'df.parquet.gzip'
        df.to_parquet(parquet_filename, index=False)
        s3_url = 's3://mybucket/parquet_test/bucket.parquet.gzip'
        df.to_parquet(s3_url, compression='gzip')
```

Edit:

So, I think with Pandas I can do this a lot more directly:

```
with S3Connect() as s3:
    obj = s3.s3_client.get_object(Bucket=input_bucket, Key=object_key)
    count = 0
    for df in pd.read_json("s3://path/to/file.json.gz", lines=True, chunksize=50000000):
        count += 1
        parquet_filename = f'df_{str(count)}.parquet.gzip'
        df.to_parquet(parquet_filename, index=False)
        s3_url = f's3://parquet_test/{parquet_filename}'
        df.to_parquet(s3_url, compression='gzip')
        # The file is also being saved locally, which I don't want
        # so I'm just doing this to remove it
        os.remove(parquet_filename)
```

Comment: While you can fetch from s3 in chunks, you cannot unzip in chunks. Your chunks will need to be reassembled into the archive to decompress it. Perhaps chunking your data into multiple archives at compression time would help.

Comment: You should be able to use the [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) `Decompress` object to decompress chunks. However, there is no guarantee that your chunks will contain whole lines, so you'll need to patch together lines that cross chunk boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

Gzip needs to know when the end of the file occurs, so by passing it small chunks of data at a time, you're in effect telling it these are small gzip files, which it's failing on since they end early.  `gzip.open`, on the other hand, can be passed a file, or file-like object, and it will use the returns from `read` to know when the file ends.

So, you can simply pass it the output object from `get_object`, and let it request data from the S3 object as it needs it, and understand when the gzip file ends.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=input_bucket, Key=object_key)['Body']
with gzip.open(s3_object, "r") as f:
    for row in f:
        row = json.loads(row)
        # TODO: Handle each row as it comes in...
        print(row)
```